# Service Fabric - A web api in cluster who' only job is to serve data from reliable collection

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am new to Service Fabric and currently I am struggling to find out how to access data from reliable collection (That is defined, and initialized in a Statefull Service context) from a WEB API (that is, also living in the Service fabric cluster, as a separate application). The problem is very basic and I am sure I am missing something very obvious. So apologies to the community if this sounds lame.

I have a large XML, a portions of which I want to expose via a WEB API endpoints as results from various queries . Searched for similar questions, but couldn't find a suitable answer.

Would be happy to see how an experienced SF developer would do such task.

**EDIT** I posted the solution i have came up with

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading around and observing others issues and Azure's samples, I have implemented a solution. Posting here the gotchas I had, hoping that will help other devs that are new to Azure Service fabric (Disclaimer: I am still a newbie in Service Fabric, so comments and suggestions are highly appreciated):

First, pretty simple - I ended up with a stateful service and a WEB Api Stateless service in an azure service fabric application:

- `DataStoreService` - Stateful service that is reading the large XMLs and stores them into Reliable dictionary (happens in the RunAsync method).
- Web Api provides an `/api/query` endpoint that filters out the Collection of XElements that is stored in the rteliable dictionary and serialize it back to the requestor

**3 Gotchas**

*1) How to get your hands on the reliable dictionary data from the Stateless service, i.e how to get an instance of the Stateful service from Stateless one* :

```
ServiceUriBuilder builder = new ServiceUriBuilder("DataStoreService");
IDataStoreService DataStoreServiceClient = ServiceProxy.Create<IDataStoreService>(builder.ToUri(), new ServicePartitionKey("Your.Partition.Name"));
```

Above code is already giving you the instance. I.e - you need to use a service proxy. For that purpose you need:

- define an interface that your stateful service will implement, and use it when invoking the Create method of ServiceProxy (`IDataStoreService`)
- Pass the correct Partition Key to Create method. [This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2015/10/13/understanding-service-fabric-partitions/) gives very good intro on Azure Service Bus partiotions

*2) Registering of Replica listeners* - in order to avoid errors saying

> The primary or stateless instance for the partition 'a67f7afa-3370-4e6f-ae7c-15188004bfa1' has invalid address, this means that right address from the replica/instance is not registered in the system

, you need to register replica listeners as stated in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590933/the-primary-or-stateless-instance-for-the-partition-has-invalid-address) :

```
    public DataStoreService(StatefulServiceContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
        configurationPackage = Context.CodePackageActivationContext.GetConfigurationPackageObject("Config");
    }
```

*3) Service fabric name spacing and referencing services* - the `ServiceUriBuilder` class I took from the [service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-web-reference-app). Basically you need something to generate an Uri of the form:

`new Uri("fabric:/" + this.ApplicationInstance + "/" + this.ServiceInstance);`,
where `ServiceInstance` is the name of the service you want to get instance of (`DataStoreService` in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebAPI with OWIN to setup a communication listener and expose data from your reliable collections.  See [Build a web front end for your app](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi/) for info on how to set that up.  Take a look at the WordCount sample in the [Getting started sample apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/samples/service-fabric-dotnet-getting-started/), which feeds a bunch of random words into a stateful service and keeps a count of the words processed.  Hope that helps.