# How to add listeners to Actor Application?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm calling a stateless service in the actor using the below code:

to solve this we must add the listeners, [The primary or stateless instance for the partition has invalid address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36590933/the-primary-or-stateless-instance-for-the-partition-has-invalid-address)

But this method (CreateServiceReplicaListeners)vis not available in to override from Actor to register the remote.

How must this be done when we want to make a remote call from actor to service ?

Comment: Could you please write an example of communication between services? It is not clear who calls who.

Comment: @ cassandrad : Updated the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Add this to your **Stateless Service code**, liked described
    [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting):

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new[] { new ServiceInstanceListener(context => 
        this.CreateServiceRemotingListener(context)) };
}
```

2.In your **Actor**, call the service like this:

```
var carUpdate = ServiceProxy.Create<ICarUpdate>(new Uri("fabric:/App/Car"));
await carUpdate.ProcessCarUpdate();
```

Comment: this worked. I'm facing another issue now, I'm passing an delegate inside the ProcessCarUpdate(delegate) and this exception is being thrown "Type 'System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry' with data contract name 'DelegateSerializationHolder.DelegateEntry:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver if you are using DataContractSerializer or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to the serializer."

Comment: Your datacontracts must be DataContractSerializable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-notes-on-actor-type-serialization

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms731923.aspx